# Pull specific content from HTTPGET request

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, httprequest, http

Is there a way to only grab specific content from an HTTPGET request?  For example, if the content I need for the email is contained within the `<div id="the_content">` tag.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div id="the_content">
    I only want to grab the content within this div
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I thought I saw something on this forum which showed how to do this, but unable to find it.

Thanks!

Comment: Forgot to mention this is for Exact Target. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there's any native HTML parser in Apex, you'd have to parse through the httpresponse.getBody() just like any other string.

See [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000091IxIAI), and [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AykcIAC) for a way to do regex expression pattern matching which might help.